# Trying to build a case structure

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a case structure using If/ElseIf statements, but I'm not sure what to dimension my "Region" variable to use a decision variable to be used later on. (Say later I want to add more code based on what the Region the variable falls into) Can anyone help?

```
Dim Region 

Dim RegionString As String

RegionString = TransmittalSubmittalActiveWorksheet.Range("A1").Value

    If RegionString Like "*NORTH*" Then ' "North" is case sensitive
        Debug.Print RegionString
        Region = NORTH
        Debug.Print Region
    ElseIf RegionString Like "*WEST*" Then
        Debug.Print RegionString
        Region = WEST
    ElseIf RegionString Like "*CHICAGO*" Then
        Debug.Print RegionString
        Region = CHICAGO
    ElseIf RegionString Like "*SOUTH*" Then
        Debug.Print RegionString
        Region = SOUTH
    ElseIf RegionString Like "*NUCLEAR*" Then
        Debug.Print RegionString
        Region = NUCLEAR
    End If
```

Comment: For now (without knowing the future requirements), Dim Region as String.  And change NORTH to become "NORTH", etc for the other constants.  When future needs arise, then change String to another type.

Comment: Is the value of `NORTH` actually "NORTH" (and likewise for the others?)

Comment: Thanks! @donPablo

Comment: You can also use a `Select Case` which is faster and easier to read in my opinion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Comment: What might a `RegionString` contain?  What is the value of `NORTH` in `Region=NORTH`?  What data type is it?